# How can I hide a button based on row content in a lighting:dataTable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning:dataTable control in a lightning component I'm developing. I have a column in that dataTable of type 'button'.
​

I want to be able to hide the button in that column, based upon the value of another column in that row.

Is there a way I can do this, while still using lighting:dataTable?
By way of example:

`Component
    <lightning:dataTable
        columns="{! v.gridColumns }"
        data="{! v.gridData }"
        keyField="Document"
        hideCheckboxColumn = "true"
        aura:id="myTree"/>`

`Controller`

```
onInit: function (component, event, helper) {        
    var columns = [];
    columns.push({type: 'button', label: 'Button Column', fieldName: 'detailPage', typeAttributes: {name: 'show_details', label: 'My Page'}});
    columns.push({type: 'text', fieldName: 'DocumentCategory', label: 'Document Category'});

    component.set('v.gridColumns', columns);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have? Can't we add a class to lightning: button to hide it?

Comment: lightning:dataTable doesn't give me the flexibility to specify anything on the button beyond: "disabled, iconName, iconPosition, label, name, title, variant"  
Out of the box it handles creating the markup for buttons.

Comment: Typically, you would need to capture some kind of event, and then find the button from the target or target source in the event to add a class like slds-hide.

Comment: But that seems overly complex for something that you should be able to handle declaratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a reasonable solution. It still renders a small "Line" in the place of the button, but what I wound up doing was binding the button's disabled attribute to field on my result set, and then setting the button label to be an empty string.

e.g.

---

Where "detailPage" is the record, and "buttonLabel" and "disableMe" are fields on the record.
"buttonLabel" and "disableMe" are set in the helper based upon the content of the record.

```
onInit: function (component, event, helper) {        
var columns = [];
columns.push({type: 'button', label: 
"Button Column", fieldName: 'detailPage', 
        typeAttributes: {
            name: 'navigate', 
            label: { fieldName: 'buttonLabel'},
            disabled: { fieldName: 'disableMe'}
        }
    });
columns.push({type: 'text', fieldName: 'DocumentCategory', label: 'Document Category'});

component.set('v.gridColumns', columns);
}
```